# The limit of $\frac{3^x+4^x}{2^x + 5^x}$ as x approaches infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How do I do this problem? The x is in the exponents.

Comment: How could someone solve this by using Hopital's rule? Irrelevant tag.

Comment: I meant without lhospital. Thanks for fixing it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factor out a $5^x$ from the numerator and denominator:
$$
\frac{3^x+4^x}{2^x+5^x}=\frac{(3/5)^x+(4/5)^x}{(2/5)^x+1}
$$
Now what happens as $x\to\infty$?

Comment: Why did you choose to divide by 5^x? is it because it is the highest base?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the trick.

Comment: So if 4^x and 5^x was switched, with 5^x being in the numerator and 4^x being in the denominator, would you still divide by 5^x?

Comment: Yes. In that case, the numerator would go to $1$, the denominator to $0$, so the limit would be $\infty$.

Comment: Wait I'm confused. So I divided by 5^x and I got that step, but I still have the exponents left. How would I know how to solve this problem? How did dividing by 5^x help; it just turned 5^x to 1 and the others to fractions.

Comment: What is $\lim_{x\to\infty} (2/5)^x$? What happens when you raise a fraction less than $1$ to a large power?

Comment: It makes it 0. So if I evaluate each one, then the limit would be 0+0/0+1 = 0?

Comment: Now you got it!

Comment: Thank you so so much!! One more thing: what did you mean when you said "Yes. In that case, the numerator would go to 1, the denominator to 0, so the limit would be ∞. – " for my other scenario? Why is it ∞-?

Answer (score 2):

Hint : Divide numerator and denominator by $5^x$